# Turbo C gives Output as 0.000000

Tags: c, turbo-c

I have set the correct directory paths for Turbo C. But yet it gives the output as 0.000000

Following is the program:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int n;
    float r, si, ci, p;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter principle amount\n");
    scanf("%f", &p);
    printf("enter rate of interest\n");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("enter number of years\n");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    si = p * n * r / 100;
    ci = p * (pow((1 + (r / 100)), n) - 1);
    printf("simple interest=%f\n", si);
    printf("compound interest=%f", ci);
    getch();
}
```

It is supposed to give numbers instead of 0.000000

Any help?

Comment: Totally off-topic but do you have the option of using a more modern compiler? If you do, I strongly urge you to.

Comment: Typo: `scanf("%f",&n);` ==> `scanf("%d",&n);`

Comment: Why are you reading in rate of interest `rate` as `%d` and number of years `n` as `%f`?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&r);` no; `scanf("%f",&n);` also no. Turn on your compiler warnings, and mind them.

Comment: Why are you using Turbo C? If you google it, you'll get: Turbo C is a discontinued Integrated Development Environment and compiler for the C programming language from Borland.

Comment: Always check scanf return value to catch invalid input. Check docs to see what it means.

Comment: @machine_1  can you please suggest me modern compiler ?

Comment: You can find a list of compilers here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers

I'd recommend Clang or gcc.

Comment: I presume you are running Windows? You could try Visual Studio 2017 community edition.  It's free. It needs a reasonably modern pc to run it but tbh if you have windows 10 it'll be OK.

Comment: @Neil I will try it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
scanf("%f",&n);
```

to:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

since `n` is an integer, not a float, as suggested in the comments already.

For `r`, which is of type `float`, you should use `scanf("%f",&r);`.

PS: Consider using a modern compiler, such as GCC.

Comment: Can you please suggest me modern compiler?  Borland ?

Comment: @gsamaras You seem to have mixed up the two `scanf` calls – for `r` and for `n`. Both are mistaken in the OP, but your first snippet is a hybrid of them (which is actually correct for `r`).

Comment: Thank you ALL ; it works now ; I will use modern compiler like GCC

Comment: @Paramasivan Good decision.